# How to make sure a number with digits no more than 2 in java

Tags: java, format

I have some number values, and I want to make sure they hold up to 2 digits.

For example:

```
11.1233 --> 11.12
11.1    --> 11.1
123     --> 123
```

I have thought of using

```
String.format("%.2f",11.1233)
```

This works well for number more than 2 digits, but it will add extra `0` to the other, for example,it will cause the following result:

```
11.1 --> 11.10
123  --> 123.00
```

While I do not need the extra `0`.

Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to suppress the non-significant digits

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.##"); 
format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
System.out.println(format.format(11.1233));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this...

```
Double num = 11.111;
Double d = Math.Floor(num * 100) / 100
```

Depends if you want to store the other digits or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
double a = 11.1233;
double b = 11.1;
double c = 123;
System.out.println(nf.format(Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.2f",a))));
System.out.println(nf.format(Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.2f",b))));
System.out.println(nf.format(Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.2f",c))));
```